# Logging in C# console application

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I need to write a console application and enable logging in it. I have written Program and even loggng fnctionality

```
static class log
{
    public static void LogFile(string filename, string sExceptionMessage, string sexception,  string target, string temporary)
    {
        StreamWriter log;

        if (!File.Exists(temporary + "\\" + "Failed" + "\\" + "logfile.txt"))
        {
            log = new StreamWriter(temporary + "\\" + "Failed" + "\\" + "logfile.txt");
        }
        else
        {
            log = File.AppendText(temporary + "\\" + "Failed" + "\\" + "logfile.txt");
        }

        // Write to the file:
        log.WriteLine("Filename:" + filename);
        log.WriteLine("Data Time:" + DateTime.Now);
        log.WriteLine("Exception Message:" + sExceptionMessage);
        log.WriteLine("Exception:" + sexception);
        log.WriteLine("Target Site:" + target + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);

        // Close the stream:
        log.Close();
    }
}
```

but problem is my lead have asked me to write logging functioanlity using .Net logging framework.
Can someone help me with this.Which library is available in .net console for logging.
In Web application IIS functionality can be use but I have no idea in terms of Console.Please help.
Does it mean using log4net beacuse this is what i found out googling.can someone please confirm

Thanks

Comment: I would ask your lead, but to me it does sound like log4net (granted this is opinion based)

Comment: yes, log4net is great. This [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial) is very useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot,even i had same in mind.I was confused with word ".net framework for Logging".

Comment: "my lead have asked me to ..." - please talk to that person and figure out what needs to be done. SO is not a place to clarify requirements. Note that " .Net logging framework" may also mean built in .Net logging. While log4net suggested by @AndreySarafanov is one of popular logging frameworks it is not the built in one and definitely not the only one.

Comment: That was just because I wanted to explain the scenario sir.Is there any built In logging in .net for console application.?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: thanks for the link.I will check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your lead was referring to any .NET logging framework, since there is not a 'definitive' framework as such.

Here is a list of some [options](http://www.dotnetlogging.com/comparison/).

Personally I do like log4net, but there are plenty of other ways to skin this cat.
Log4net (and the others too, I should imagine) involves 3 main steps:

1. Adding appropriate configuration in app.config to establish how and where to log
2. Writing some code on application startup to 'configurate' the logger
3. Declare a class-level logger variable at each class you intent to log. (And explicitly calling its methods in order to do the actual logging).

*PS: For building URLs, I would highly recommend*

```
System.IO.Path.Combine
```

*which takes an enumeration of strings, and safely includes backslashes as appropriate.*